# Как увидеть обновленный icon после компиляции? Windows 10

Tags: windows, explorer, delphi-xe2

Я поменял ICON файл .ico для .exe файла и хотел бы увидеть изменения, но видимо windows кэширует иконки. Как "почистить кэш" и видеть в проводнике новую иконку? Сама новая иконка осталась со старым именем и тоже выглядит по старому, но после открытия показывает что внутри новая иконка.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-icon-clear-thumbnail-cache-windows-10 , а так можно переименовывать файлы и смотреть)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, отпишите как ответ, в частности раздел "Clear Thumbnail cache in Windows 10" помог решить задачу. Если перевести и записать как ответ, с указанием источника — цены не будет.